# Reformat image format in PDF

Tags: pdf, telerik, itext

I got issues in rendering a couple of images and texts in PDF in Telerik PDF viewer - according to Telerik's documentation it seems those texts/images formats are incompatible.

Are there ways to convert existing images in a PDF and replace it back to the PDF so to make the file compatible to the Telerik PDF viewer?

Many thanks

Comment: Does Telerik explain in what way they are *incompatible*?

Comment: You could change renderer to another, which generates compatible for viewing format. Provide us details, please.